# How to utilize Facades in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to know Is it possible to utilize Laravel Facades without importing them to scope  by 'use' statement?

```
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;


Route::get('/home',function(Request $request){
    Cookie::queue('userIp',$request->ip(),2);
        return view('home');
});
```

I tried it and it worked!(Laravel 10.x)
Cookie and Route facades worked without importing them to web.php file!

Comment: Why are you asking if it's possible, and then immediately answer your own question? Yes it's possible, but is not recommended.

Comment: I asked this question because I didn't know what was happening behind the scenes and  in Laravel's doc, wherever facades were used, they were imported before. @miken32

Comment: "How does it work" is a very different question. Aliases are dumped into the global namespace when the app starts up. The aliases are specified in `config/app.php`. In modern Laravel versions, this is mostly populated by the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::defaultAliases()` method.

Comment: And just a language note, the `use` statements at the top of the file are not "importing" classes, just aliasing them. But the `use` statements inside a class are importing traits.

Comment: php doc calls it importing .For example, look at example#1 title at following link. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php @miken32

Comment: Interesting, in the first part of the page they use both, seeming to prefer aliasing. But by the end of the page they’re only using importing. Confusion reigns!

Comment: I only made the distinction to clarify that nothing actually gets imported, all you’re doing is advising the compiler “when I say `Route` I mean this longer name.” The name isn’t even checked until you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**helpers**](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers) or **Dependency Injection** of that facade I recommend checking docs about what are the [diffs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/facades#when-to-use-facades).

You have Dependency Injection when in the class you "inject" via the constructor, laravel does it a lot, you can check more on [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container#introduction).

Comment: the doc says: when u wants to utilize facades u should include them for example to your web.php. but It's working for me without including! @francisco

Comment: I'ts by [this](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades#facade-class-reference)

Answer (score 0):

All alias names are kept in an aliases array inside the app.php config file, which is located inside the /config directory.

If we take a look at the array, we can see that each alias name is mapped to a fully-qualified class name. This means we can use any name that we wish for a facade class:
Okay, now let’s see how Laravel uses this array for aliasing the facade classes. In the bootstrapping phase, Laravel uses a service named AliasLoader which is part of the Illuminate\Foundation package. AliasLoader takes the aliases array, iterates over all the elements, and creates a queue of __autoload functions using PHP’s spl_autoload_register. Each __autoload function is responsible for creating an alias for the respective facade class by using PHP’s class_alias function.

**As a result, we won’t have to import and alias the classes before using them as we normally do with the use directive.**
[www.sitepoint.com](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-laravel-facades-work-and-how-to-use-them-elsewhere/)